# Why does my gas engine sound like a diesel?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, noise, diagnostics, impala

I have a 2011 Chevy Impala 3.9L police package car. I've had to issue with the engine running rough, stuttering, burning oil etc...but, when I am at idle, parked, or in traffic; I can hear a very faint ticking noise coming from the engine (sounds like a diesel engine) and is never present when moving. Am I being paranoid or this normal?

Comment: Have you checked the oil to ensure it is up to level? Also, how many miles on the car?

Comment: Just changed the oil yesterday. Checked it this morning and it's normal as well.......

Comment: How many miles?

Comment: It's got 95k so far. All schedule maintenance were up to date.

Comment: My thinking is you have a noisy lifter/rocker arm which, when the oil pressure is low at idle, you hear it. When you are above idle, the oil pressure is enough to cause the noise to quit. This is an over head valve (OHV) design, which means it has lifters and rocker arms. It could just be one of them is just noisy.

Comment: So nothing to be concerned about?